# Laravel composer package eloquent relationships

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

I've created my first composer package for Laravel 8. It provides a user group model and some routes. A couple of them are

```
POST     | api/v1/usergroups             | usergroups.create   | ITGuy1990\Usergroups\Controllers\UsergroupController@create   | api
GET|HEAD | api/v1/usergroups             | usergroups.index    | ITGuy1990\Usergroups\Controllers\UsergroupController@index    | api
GET|HEAD | api/v1/usergroups/{usergroup} | usergroups.show     | ITGuy1990\Usergroups\Controllers\UsergroupController@show     | api
PATCH    | api/v1/usergroups/{usergroup} | usergroups.update   | ITGuy1990\Usergroups\Controllers\UsergroupController@update   | api
DELETE   | api/v1/usergroups/{usergroup} | usergroups.destroy  | ITGuy1990\Usergroups\Controllers\UsergroupController@destroy  | api
```

All working fine so far. But now the hard part. Outside of the package, and in my Laravel application I am going to add another eloquent model. A `TodoList` model. Now, i want to make a "one to many" relationship between a `UserGroup` model and `TodoList` model. I want the `api/v1/usergroups/{usergroup}` route to also return the `TodoList` models associated to the `UserGroup` model. I figured that I probable want to add a query parameter to select relationships to include like so: `http://localhost:8000/api/v1/usergroups/1?include=todolists`

But how can I make the `usergroups.show` route include relationships that are not part of the `usergroups` package. I could, but do not want to include the `todolist` model in the `usergroups` package. Because I want the `usergroups` package to only be responsible for usergroups, right?

Thank you for helping me in advance.

ITGuy1990

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you are new to Laravel. If you want to show the todolist connected to each usergroup on the `usergroups.show` route, you can do it by making a model relations. If each group will have more than 1 todolist and each todolist will belong to more than 1 group, this is a many to many relation:

In UserGroup model:

```
public function todolist()
  {
     return $this->hasMany(ToDoList::class);
  }
```

In ToDoList model:

```
public function usergroups()
  {
     return $this->belongsToMany(UserGroup::class);
  }
```

In Controller:

```
$usergroups = UserGroup::with('todolist')->get();
```

In blade:

```
@foreach($usergroups->todolist as $todolist)
{{$todolist->name}}
@endforeach
```

Comment: I am not new to laravel. I know how to make relations. But as i stated I cannot put the todolist function in the usergroup model. Because that would make my usergroup composer package dependent on the todolist model class. That’s the core problem I try to solve